# Spontaneously repeated key presses

Tags: keyboard

My 13-inch, M1, 2020 MBP recently started to fire repeated key presses, both with an external keyboard and with just the built-in keyboard.

I installed KeyCastr to see which keys are fired and it seems to be a random key repeated for a zillion times, like `00000000000000000000000000` or `-------------------` or 100s of "enters". I once could bring it to stop by holding the backspace for a while, but that could be just a coincidence.

It must be a software issue no?

Reboot didn't help. Sometimes the problem goes away, and a few days later it is back...

Any idea how to find out what causes this?

Comment: I've seen this happen with older external Apple keyboards. I've attributed it to a hardware malfunction in the keyboard, but I never got a definitive answer.

Comment: @lhf it's not that, but your answer triggered a thought: I have another (3rd) keyboard in the room. This is a paired bluetooth keyboard on a desk where someone else works.... Mystery solved!